# How to send a message in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

How do you send a normal message when a user types the command? I have tried using @client.command
async def ping
but it does not work D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `await ctx.send("Your message here")`, make sure that you have Context passed in your `@client.command`.
If you have anymore questions, feel free to ask me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a guide if it helps

```
@client.command
async def ping(ctx):
await ctx.send("Your message")
```

Answer (score 0):

here `ctx` is the context and `hi` is command

Code:

```py
@client.command
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Message which you want to send")
```